# When doing a Firebase deploy my browser seems to cache my websites files so I dont see the latest

Tags: angular, firebase, caching, webpack, firebase-hosting

When doing a Firebase deploy my browser seems to cache my websites files so I dont see the latest.

**I'm using Firebase, Angular version 4 and webpack.**

I do a firebase deploy and my browser still shows old html.

I have a Firebase.json file and I set the max age of the cache control to 0:

```
"source" : "**/*.@(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)",
"headers" : [ {
"key" : "Cache-Control",
"value" : "max-age=0"
```

Do I need to add .html and .css to the source?

Comment: are you experiencing this for just images or html, js as well, by the looks of it seems you are controlling cache for just images.

Comment: @MadhuRanjan I'm experiencing this for my HTML, I updated a html page and I even did a hard refresh and could not see the HTML. I had to check in incognito mode in chrome to see my changes. Could you show me your firebase.json file ?

Comment: did you add `html` in source in Firebase.json? are you using angular-cli build or you have your own build process using webpack? In  angular-cli build any updated file gets an updated name, which also helps cache busting.

Comment: No I havent tried adding html in the source. Did you add html to your source? yeah I'm using angular-cli webpack

Comment: Can you check if the browser is actually requesting the file from the server, or whether it's getting it from cache. If it's getting it from the server, it might be that one of the CDN edges didn't get the update. Try redeploying the web with `firebase deploy`. If that doesn't fix it, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Comment: I spoke to cloudflare which I use and they said it could be firebase varnish. And that firebase need to purge it. I've done a firebase deploy and messaged firebase today. No reply from firebase yet

Comment: @MadhuRanjan it seems the html comes through but the style.bundle.css is always the same name and therefore caching